# Is there a way to view edges in weight paint mode?

Tags: weight-painting

It would make the process a bit easier I am aware of face-select mode but I don't like the way that works. I would like to be able to weight paint across all faces as I normally would without either weight or vertex selection but with my edges more visible. I am aware of wireframe mode but... obviously that does not give you the visual cues you need for weight painting.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the [wireframe overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVuNS.png)?

Comment: I forgot that option but that was exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the *Wireframe* Option (under [Geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#geometry)) in the [Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#viewport-overlays) while in weight paint mode.

[image: wireframe overlay]

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but the *Wireframe* option remains visible both in weight paint and object mode. This means it adds a wireframe overlay for every visible object in your scene. The *Show Wire* option performs the same function as *Wireframe*, but it is only visible on objects in weight paint mode.

While in weight paint mode, you'll find [Weight Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#weight-paint) options immediately below the Geometry section of the [Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#viewport-overlays) menu. *Show Wire* is at the bottom of this section.

[image: Geometry and Weight Paint options]

Comment: Show Wire does have the stange property that any face currently selected in edit mode will *not* show wires in weight paint mode. I haven't found a use for this, but it's worth being aware of.